# Getting an Error on console while saving data in firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

here is my Javascript code. its simply copy from the firebase Docs

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.2/firebase.js"/></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: ".",
        authDomain: ".",
        databaseURL: ".",
        projectId: ".",
        storageBucket: ".",
        messagingSenderId: ".[enter image description here][1]"
    };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

    // Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
    
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    function submitCountry(){
    console.log('in funtion');
    db.collection("cities").doc("asdasLA").set({
        name: "Los Angeles",
        state: "CasdasA",
        stasdaate: "CasdasdasA",
        stasaasddaate: "CAasd",
        country: "USA"
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });
}
</script>
```

when i refresh my page it show the uncaught error.

> {code: "app/duplicate-service", message: "Firebase: Firebase service
> named 'firestore' already registered (app/duplicate-service).", name:
> "firestore", stack: "firestore: Firebase: Firebase service named
> 'fires…m/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase-firestore.js:1:326255"} firebase @
> index.esm.js:17591 (anonymous) @ index.esm.js:41 index.esm.js:17591
>
> Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate firebase-firestore - be sure to
> load firebase-app.js first.

after clicking my save button it shows the error mention below.

when i use the same code on simple project without any JS or Bootstrap it works fine but same code i placed in My real project with Bootstrap it shows errors

> [Intervention] Slow network is detected. See  for more details.
> Fallback font will be used while loading:

Comment: what error.....

Comment: @Badgy i posted my errors.

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.2/firebase.js"/></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

you load the 'firestore' Firebase service twice, see the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

You should either do

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.2/firebase.js"></script>
```

or

```
<!-- Firebase App is always required and must be first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- Add additional services that you want to use -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

Also note that in your code you have mixed versions (i.e. 5.4.2 and 5.3.0). Most probably something to avoid.

---

Following your comment below, in order to check that it writes correctly to the db, modify you code as follows and just open the HTML page (the `set()` method will be triggered automatically)

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: ".",
        authDomain: ".",
        databaseURL: ".",
        projectId: ".",
        storageBucket: ".",
        messagingSenderId: ".[enter image description here][1]"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    // Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase

    var db = firebase.firestore();

    db.collection("cities").doc("asdasLA").set({
        name: "Los Angeles",
        state: "CasdasA",
        stasdaate: "CasdasdasA",
        stasaasddaate: "CAasd",
        country: "USA"
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you set some specific security rules that would prevent the write?

Comment: Are you calling the `submitCountry()` function? I also see that you don't end the function properly.

Comment: Yes i am calling Submit Country()

Comment: It should save the data then

Comment: Did you try to use the HTML page I provided in the answer? Put the correct values for the `config` object, save it as html on your computer, and open it with the browser of your choice. It should write to the DB.